# Higher-Order Component Being Called Multiple Times

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, higher-order-components

I've created the following Higher-Order Component:

```
const baseComponent = (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentClass<any>) => (props: IKeyValue) => {
  if (props.isLoading) {
    return (
      <LoadingSpinnerComponent shown={true} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <WrappedComponent {...props} />
  );
};
```

This is causing this component to be called indefinitely.
(`componentDidMount` in `myComponent` will, means, this component is being recreated).

I am using it in the following way:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  dispatchToProps,
)(baseComponent(myComponent)) as React.ComponentClass<any>;
```

When removing the if part:

```
  if (props.isLoading) {
    return (
      <LoadingSpinnerComponent shown={true} />
    );
  }
```

The component will be called only once. 
I tried to debug deep inside the react lib code but the magic is a wonder for me. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The full code:
`myComponent`:

```
class MiniCatalogContainer extends React.PureComponent<IProps, void> {
  public componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchCatalog} = this.props;
    fetchCatalog({path});
  }

  public render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  dispatchToProps,
)(baseComponent(MyComponent)) as React.ComponentClass<any>;
```

`promise-middleware`

```
import { Dispatch } from 'react-portal/src/interfaces';
import isPromise from 'react-portal/src/utils/is-promise';

interface IOptions {
  dispatch: Dispatch;
}

export default function promiseMiddleware({ dispatch }: IOptions) {
  return (next: Dispatch) => (action: any) => {
    if (!isPromise(action.payload)) {
      return next(action);
    }

    const { types, payload, meta } = action;
    const { promise, data } = payload;
    const [ PENDING, FULFILLED, REJECTED ] = types;

   /**
    * Dispatch the pending action
    */
    dispatch( { type: PENDING,
                ...(data ? { payload: data } : {}),
                ...(meta ? { meta } : {}),
    });

    /**
     * If successful, dispatch the fulfilled action, otherwise dispatch
     * rejected action.
     */
    return promise.then(
      (result: any) => {
        dispatch({
          meta,
          payload: result,
          type: FULFILLED,
        });
      },
      (error: any) => {
        dispatch({
          meta,
          payload: error,
          type: REJECTED,
        });
      },
    );
  };
}
```

SOLUTION:

As @Shleng noticed, the loop is because of my `fetch` call inside the component. I ended up with the simple solution:

```
const baseComponent = (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentClass<any>) => (props: IKeyValue) => {
      if (props.isLoading) {
        return (
          <LoadingSpinnerComponent shown={true} />
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        );
      }

      return (
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      );
    };
```

Comment: are you dispatching some action that will change `isLoading` in myComponent's `componentDidMount`?

Comment: It looks like your `props.isLoading` property doesn't get a stable value after initialization. Tracing its value might help.

Comment: Can you show us the `mapStateToProps`. How do all components get notified of whether they are loading or not? Do you have a `componentType.loading` state key or do they all rely on a variation of state to determine the loading property that `mapStateToProps` passes down

Comment: @Sheng yes! but one set's it to `isLoading=true` and the next to false. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you call `fetchCatalog` inside wrapped component's `componentDidMount`, so the workflow results in a loop as illustrated below:

```
mount WrappedComponent -> fetch -> mount Spinner -> loaded -> mount WrappedComponent -> fetch (loop!)

isLoading: false       -> true                   -> false                            -> true
```

Comment: Indeed, I did not see that. Thanks!